# Install latest intel-video driver on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, xorg, video

I'm having troubles when capturing video with guvcview, in a random way the Xorg server crashes and the session is restarted.

I made a post on Xorg list and they suggest me install the latest intel - video driver. The problem is that Intel doesn't have the installer of the latest driver for Ubuntu 12.04. Ubuntu 12.04 was deprecated for they, thing sounds reasonable.

So the alternative that I have:

1) Install the driver from source.

2) Make a backport from the driver for 14.04 to 12.04.

3) Something else (Upgrade the distribution isn't an alternative).

What path you suggest me to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Gustavo.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a more recent driver, along with a recent kernel, with Ubuntu LTS Enablement Stack:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

To install the **Saucy** hardware enablement packages in Precise, please run instead the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy
```